# Select Range of records using created_at

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to select a range of model records via created_at attribute, I tried this query

```
Client.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', 30.days.from_now, DateTime.now.utc)
```

But it return an empty array.

```
1.9.3-p125 :029 > Client.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', 30.days.from_now, DateTime.now.utc)
  Posting Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `clients`.* FROM `clients` WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2012-09-22 16:30:04' AND '2012-08-23')
 => []
```

Also I want to group this records into array of arrays using `.day` method,
I mean if I've 10 records I wanna group records which have created in the same day into separated array!

Comment: Are you downvoting everyone (including the one who deleted his/her response just now) who is answering your question? Or is it someone else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Client.
  where(created_at: 30.days.ago..Date.current).
  group_by{|u| u.created_at.to_date}
```

You can pass `where` an array of values between which you would like the results (for inclusive vs. exclusive ranges, look up the differences between `..` and `...`).

Further, you can group results by calling `group_by`, which will take a method to call, i.e. `.group_by(&:created_at)` or a block, as in my example. I used a full block because you wanted the results grouped by date rather than by specific timestamp. If you *actually* want the day of the month rather than the full date, you can also call `.group_by{ |u| u.created_at.day}`, but the date seems more useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is (note ago versus from now):

```
Client.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', 30.days.ago.utc, Time.now.utc)
```